# Is it possible to modify an entity with PATCH?

Tags: spring-boot, patch

I have an application and I want to modify my current candidate. 
Lets say my original candidate looks like this:

```
{name : "Yellow" surname : "Banana" friends = [ {friend : "apple"}]}
```

Than I want to modify this candidate like this:

```
{name : "Yellow" surname : "Banana" friends = [ {friend : "apple"}, {friend: "Coconut"}]}
```

Will patch be able to succesfully modify my candidate?

Comment: what do you mean by "patch"? Do you mean `RequestMethod.PATCH`? Please clarify.

Comment: I'm new to backend programing. And I saw that changes on already existing entities in the database can be done with a POST or PATCH methode. And I'm trying to figure out if I use a PATCH methode will update my candidate as described in the main post.

Comment: `PATCH` or `POST` or `PUT` won't be able to do anything on their own. They are just a convention to make your REST API truly restful/mature. You have to code the logic yourself (with the use of frameworks of course). If your question is what is the appropriate method for updating the resource, the short answer is: `PUT` for replacements, `PATCH` for partial changes. But if you go with `PUT` for partial changes it won't be a big mistake.